# Deserializing enum Shape.OBJECT using Jackson fails

Tags: java, json, serialization, enums, jackson

I have the following enum declaration:

```
@Document
@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
@JsonAutoDetect()
public enum Compass {
    north("Upper Center"),
    south("Lower Center"),
    east("Left Center"),
    west("Right Center"),
    ne("Upper Right"),
    nw("Upper Left"),
    se("Lower Right"),
    sw("Lower Left"),
    ;

    @JsonProperty   
    private String presentableName;
    @JsonProperty   
    private String name;

    private Compass() {}
    private Compass(String presentableName) {
        this.presentableName = presentableName;
    }

    public String getPresentableName() {
        return presentableName;
    }
    public void setPresentableName(String presentableName) {
        this.presentableName = presentableName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Compass fromObject(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("presentableName") String presentableName) { 
        return Compass.sw;
    }
}
```

The input arrives as a json object and most of it is deserialized correctly, but the relevant part is as below, where `placement` is a `Compass`:

```
{"placement":{"name":"se","presentableName":"Lower Right"}}
```

Deserialization doesn't work.  I thought a `JsonCreator` would work here, but for some reason I'm getting a

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

which is actually just a symptom of deserialization failure.

If I change the creator to:

```
@JsonCreator
public static Compass fromObject(@JsonProperty("name") String name) { 
    return Compass.sw;
}
```

It gets even more wierd, because now name equals `{` instead of `se` (which looks like a bug in the json object, but it's the same object that got deserialized a second ago so it's probably ok)

I'm using `jackson 2.2.3` which is the latest right now.

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace? I am just guessing but it could be that you are miss-interpreting the error message.

Answer (score 7):

Whilst I still agree with [@renatoaraujoc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24553806/3136474), I've found a (somehow hacky) solution to this problem.

Just create a `@JsonCreator` annotated method which receives a `Map<String, Object>`. Jackson deserializes the compound object into a Map as passes it to the method:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum TesterEnum {
    FirstValue(1, "One"),
    SecondValue(2, "Two");

    private int id;
    private String dsc;

    TesterEnum(int id, String dsc) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dsc = dsc;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDsc(){
        return dsc;
    }
    public void setDsc(String dsc){
        this.dsc = dsc;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static TesterEnum fromObject(final Map<String, Object> obj) {
        if (obj != null && obj.containsKey("id")) {
            Integer id = null;
            if (obj.get("id") instanceof Integer) {
                id = (Integer)obj.get("id");
            } else {
                id = Integer.parseInt((String)obj.get("id"));
            }
            return fromId(id);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static TesterEnum fromId(final Integer id) {
        if (id != null) {
            for (TesterEnum e : TesterEnum.values()) {
                if (id.equals(e.getId())) return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

P.S.: You don't really need the `fromId` method, it can be all put into `fromObject`, but I use the first on other parts of the system and like to have this separation.

P.S.²: Jackson normally decode the `id` field into an `Integer` instance, so it enters the `if (obj.get("id") instanceof Integer)` on `fromObject`, but I've seen it being cast to `String` sometimes, that's why I'm checking.

Comment: Can you please tell how the above code is working? I mean why the code with Map works, but not the other one? @dinei

Comment: @RoyalTiger Sorry, but I can't. It's been almost three years and I don't even work with C# on a daily basis anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If you mouse over the annotation @JsonFormat, it's explicit in its text that Enums can be serialized but they can't be reversed IF you choose JsonFormat. Shape.Object. So, if you want to be able to go back and forth with your Enums, leave them without this annotation. Hope it helps you, later.